# Me da error con en modificar base de datos desde C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

[image: No se por que me da ese error ya intente cambiar el parametro de where pero aun me sigue dando este error, estoy trabajando con mysql]

> Este es mi código pero no se si habrá algún problema con la sentencia que he hecho

```
 public void modificar(Int32 cantidad, String producto, String tipo_pedido, Double total)
    {
        conexion.operacion("UPDATE pedidos set  PRODUCTO=" + producto + "', TIPO_PEDIDO = '" + tipo_pedido + "', TOTAL=" + total+" WHERE CANTIDAD = " + cantidad);
    }

 private void btnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cPedidos pedido = new cPedidos();
        if (rdbDoimicilio.Checked == true)
        {
            rdbDoimicilio.Text = "Para llevar";
            String domicilio = rdbDoimicilio.Text;
            pedido.modificar(Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text), cmbOpciones.Text, domicilio, Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text));
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha modificado");
        }
        else 
        {
            rdbLocal.Text = "Cosumo local";
            String llevar = rdbLocal.Text;
            pedido.modificar(Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text), cmbOpciones.Text, llevar, Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text));
            MessageBox.Show("Se ha modificado");
        }
      }
```

[image: Y ese es el programa]

Comment: Según veo te falta una comilla simple justo al final del signo igual "UPDATE pedidos set  PRODUCTO="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la tercera linea te falta cerrar la comilla

```
conexion.operacion("UPDATE pedidos set  PRODUCTO=" + producto + "', TIPO_PEDIDO = '" + tipo_pedido + "', TOTAL=" + total+" WHERE CANTIDAD = " + cantidad + '"');
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero las preguntas que tienen errores tipograficos como este no han de responderse si no cerrarse bajo ese motivo. Si no se tiene la capacidad de votar, pulsa en reportar. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta abrir la comillas en después de

```
UPDATE pedidos set  PRODUCTO="
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero las preguntas que tienen errores tipograficos como este no han de responderse si no cerrarse bajo ese motivo. Si no se tiene la capacidad de votar, pulsa en reportar. Un saludo